# Excel formula to extract the part of a string that is before the second slash, where the text in between may be different lengths

Tags: extract

Here are some examples:
2002/12/256
or
2020/180/25

In Excel, I want to extract out the text before the second slash character, to end up with "2002/12"
or
"2020/180"

I've scoured through all the pages I can that look like solutions, but can't seem to find the one that fits this simple extraction?

Can anyone help?

cheers
Kaz

Comment: Using perl regex, it's simple. Suppose variable `kk` holds the original string. Do `$kk =~ m{^([^/]*/[^/]*)/}`, then the result ends up in the perl predefined variable `$1`. I think you'd better clarify which tool or language you are using.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I've edited the question... this is about Excel formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the raw data has exactly two slashes, then this may help.

Suppose cell "A1" contains "2002/12/256", use this formula in another cell: `=MID(A1, 1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("/", A1, 1) + 1) - 1)`

Explanation: find the the char right before the next "/" after the first "/", get its index, and return the sub string from the beginning to that index.

Comment: That's great, many thanks.. however it is returning the second slash.. I only want the text to the left of the second slash, as per examples above. Can you advise which component  I adjust to remove that end slash? I tried playing with the +1 but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Please refer to my edited answer. Besides, you can use the "Evaluate Formula" button on "Formulas" ribbon to step into each calculation step.

Comment: Fantastic... thanks so much for your help, you're awesome! And thanks for the tip about the evaluate tool. cheers Kaz :-)